# Start CORDA cash-issuer

Tags: blockchain, corda

How can I run the Corda cash-issuer App? Which parameter do I need to use?

I have just started experimenting with Blockchain technologies.
I have tried to run the CORDA cash-issuer App and followed the instructions on this site:
https://github.com/corda/cash-issuer

I get stuck at step 7 (Start the issuer daemon(See "Starting the issuer daemon" below)) in the "Getting started" part.

I have built the jar following the instructions in step 6. But I have no idea what parameter I need to use for the host-port. I tried several parameters which I have used in some other Corda Apps but no one seems to be the right choice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the Corda family!

Here is the beginner guide for how to run a corDapp from the beginning. https://docs.corda.net/building-a-cordapp-index.html